# How to verify that user has clicked on the verification link sent after contact form 7 submit?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7, email-verification

1. I am sending otp verification link in mail when user completes the form. For this I am using "OTP by Email for Contact Form 7 plugin". I want to verify that users are clicking on that link or not. And want to save data/or update true against the emailID user who clicked on that link. How do I do this?
2. After clicking on verification link,I want to redirect user to one page, that will have form details completed by him. Those details are saved in one js variable. How can I display his details on the page? How do I achieve this?

Please guide me with steps and solution. TIA.

Comment: Can you please post the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must use CFDB7 plugin to save CF7 data [here is an example for saving and retrieving data](https://ihatewp.com/how-to-get-submitted-data-from-contact-form-7/)
2. You need create hidden field in CF7 form and insert into it uniqID (You can use plugins for adding a unique field [cf7-submission-id](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-submission-id/)
3. create a page on the site (create a template for the page) to which you will redirect clients and check the get parameter which will be a unique id

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['client_id']) { //client_id = uniqid of form
        // Your page code
        // client_id -> this is uniqid of form, check if it exists in the database and display the data of sended form 
    }
?>
```

4. Create a link in the text of email to your created page and add a link with uniqid **your.site/your_dynamic_page?client_id[submission_id submission_id-537]**

Comment: Plugin cf7-submission-id is untested with my wordpress version.