# How to send link with unique id in mail and check if user opens it or not?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

After contact form 7 is submitted, I am sending result page link in email to user. I want to check emailid and store the data of the user when he clicks and open the result link from email. In short its a kind of email verification.
I am storing data in cf7 db. But there is no way to find that the user clicked on the link.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I'm guessing that the form entry has an ID. Use that ID in your email. Specifically on the link that the user has to click, like `example.com/confirmation?id=283`. Then on the, in this example, `/confirmation` page update the entry data that matches the ID saying that the email has been read.

Comment: Is a duplicate, [I already answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170607/14129711)